# Check for user activity in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, users, session

I'm writing a script (**to be run on a multipurpose desktop machine**) in which I want to check that there is no user activity.

**The non-activity would be defined as:**

1. Any user using GUI has not been interacting with it (=no mouse or keyboard input) in the past N minutes.
2. Any remotely ssh-connected user has not been running any commands or transferring data in the past N minutes.

### Where I've gotten so far

**ad 1)** The only thing that came to my mind is `xprintidle` which I used in the past and is a reliable way to check the idle time of the current user but doesn't seem to be usable in the "any current or future logged-in or not user" scenario.

**ad 2)** I can establish whether there is any open session using:

```
sudo netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'
```

This works great but doesn't exactly check for activity and I would like to ignore sessions which are opened but not actively used.

### Questions

1. Could you please suggest a solution for any of the 2 checks?
2. Is there any better comprehensive/universal way (e.g. program) to make these checks?